# C# changing automatic IP assination to manual IP set

Tags: c#, sockets

In this code IP will be assigned automatically to server and client will be connected to it, How can i change both to manual set?

```
//Server:
    private static void SetupServer()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
                serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, PORT));
                serverSocket.Listen(0);
                serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
                Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete");
            }

//client
public void ConnectToServer()// OK
        {
            while (!ClientSocket.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    ATTEMPTS++;
                    ClientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, PORT);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                }
            }
        }
```

Change 1:

```
// simple changing of this line solved client issue  
ClientSocket.Connect("127.0.0.99", 5555);
```

Comment: The operating system / network stack assigns machine IPs. Application-level code does not assign IPs; it only uses such.

Comment: Is it possible to give server assigned IP by code?

Comment: Possibly - depends on machine and permissions etc. Although wanting to assign an IP manually usually isn’t necessary or required and may indicate an X-Y problem. The machines should already be configured / connected to the network with IPs assigned: What is the purpose of a “manual IP”?

Comment: Also, the code above connects to the loop back so, presumably the code is running on the _same_ server?

Comment: Everything is on a localhost

Comment: I simply solved client side. But server side still is automatic...

Comment: I need to identify specific server, we won't to connect to any open connection. we will have different server on different machines.